# How to open a large file from a URL into memory and create a hash in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that will open files up to 20MB from a URL into memory.  I need to create a consistent hash.

This is be closest I could get.

```
import os, hashlib, optparse, requests

def get_remote_sha_sum(url):

  url_file = requests.get(url)
  sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

  with open(url_file, "rb") as f:
    while True:
      data = f.read(65536)
      if not data:
        break
      sha1.update(data)

  return sha1.hexdigest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  opt = optparse.OptionParser()
  opt.add_option('--url', '-u', default='https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf')

  options, args = opt.parse_args()
  print get_remote_sha_sum(options.url)
```

But it results in:

`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Response found`

I have tried dozens of things.'I went down the path of using `BitesIO` in which I am met with the same error message.

How do I open a large file in memory, buffer it, and create a hash?

Pls be kind, I'm still a little new to Python.

Comment: Actually this is not bad, your problem is that url_file is of type response, not exactly what you want, try to get the text with `.text` or `.data` I cannot remember right now

Comment: What makes you think `open(url_file, "rb")` will work? For this to work, `url_file` must be a string or buffer, as the error message says, but `requests.get` returns a `Response` object, again, as mentioned in the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you do not need to cut the file in several batches, this is not a big file.

For technical reasons I could not use the requests library, but a `string = requests.get(url).text` should work fine with the code

```
import os, hashlib, optparse, requests

def get_remote_sha_sum(url):

  # url_file = requests.get(url)
  sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
  string = """<html><body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0"><embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="4"></body></html>"""
  sha1.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
  return sha1.hexdigest()

print(get_remote_sha_sum('https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'))
```

Your problem is not  about the size of the file but about the fact url_file is a Reponse object and not a string as required by the sha1 library

Comment: Thank you for simplifying my problem, helping me understand the issue, and providing enough info for me to get over the finish line. This is what I ended up with. Works great for my PDF situation. https://gist.github.com/joelhsmith/bb65ee44b0d2c96c71c978350838c522

Comment: It looks great ! As a side note, you seem to use python 2. String in python2 does not need to be encoded before updating sha1 (As far as I remember). Congrats anyway ! :)